# Broken output rows in ShellScript

Tags: powershell, sh, gnu-make, gnu, avrdude

I would like to create an AVR programmer PowerShell script for ATmega microcontrollers. There is a [GNU Tool Chain](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/install_tools.html?fbclid=IwAR3f6tknXDBNnEfl629Nrsu4hQYM38yPD6DoXkmR_gGqtwfuEls7x6XqIRo) for Windows what provide a `make program` command. If I open a Windows Power shell window in a directory what contains C source file(s) and run the `make program`, it compiles the source code and uploads the result .hex file to the connected microcontroller via an USBasp device. Then if I get an error message, it displays properly.

[image: Properly result (img)]

However, if I write a shell script (.ps1 file), that contains the `make program` command, It breaks the error message.

[image: Broken result (img)]

How can I fix the error output of the shell script?

Comment: Have you run the script outside of ISE? If so, was the result the same?

Comment: If I have run the script outside of ISE, the result displays properly, but I want to write the stdout and stderr to the terminal window and a text file at the same time. When I use the "make program 2>&1 | tee test.txt" command, the errors breaks in the terminal window and the file too.

Comment: You should use `& { make program } 2>&1 | tee test.txt` then.

Comment: Unfortunately, it hasn't improved.